# Ant: Want to have a property that has a timestamp in it

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.2 on Ubuntu Linux (and also on Windows 7 running Cygwin).  I have this property ...

```
    <property name="results" location="${selenium.results.dir}/Results-20110922_131005.html" />
```

I would like to replace the "20110922_131005" with something less hard coded that represents the current time stamp.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<tstamp>
     <format property="time.stamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"/>
</tstamp>
```

This will create a property called `${time.stamp}`.

```
<property name="results" 
    location="${selenium.results.dir}/Results-${time.stamp}.html" />
```

Comment: Change lowercase 'mm' in pattern for month to capital 'MM'. Now it's years-minutes-day.

Comment: @DanielSitarz - whoops

Comment: And perhaps lowercase 'hh' for 12h format to capital 'HH' for 24h format.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [tstamp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) in ant. Also look at SO Question : [output timestamp in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472301/output-timestamp-in-ant)