# How make display several date/time with Ant , like your topic "output timestamp in ant"

Tags: date, ant, time

In one of your topic, named "output timestamp in ant", i've tested the 2 way explained in order to display several time in the same Ant script.

But, this 2 solutions don't work for me, Ant give me all the time the same date/time.

Anybody can explaine me why ?

I've found a solution (but note very perfet to my mind ) :

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="date.etape1" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
</tstamp>
<echo message="${date.etape1} bla bla bla...." />
<tstamp>
    <format property="date.etape2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
</tstamp>
<echo message="${date.etape2} bla bla bla...." />
```

If somebody can explain me how make work one of the 2 solutions of the topic "output timestamp in ant", i would be very happy !!!

Comment: If my memory doesn't fail on me, if you use the <tstamp /> tag you can access the ${DSTAMP} and ${TSTAMP} at runtime and then format them. However I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes, but this sample of code found in this site does'nt work for me :    <target name="testMe">
    <MyTimestamp></MyTimestamp>
    <sleep seconds="5"></sleep>
    <MyTimestamp></MyTimestamp>

</target>

<macrodef name="MyTimestamp">
    <sequential >
    <tstamp>
        <format property="current.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"/>
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="RUN_TIME: ${current.time}"/>
    </sequential> </macrodef>

Comment: try using the standard <TSTAMP/> directive as shown in here http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html and in the <echo ../> just use <echo level="info" message="TS: ${DSTAMP}/${TSTAMP}"/>

Comment: Yes, but i need seconds too, so i've to use pattern, no ? I post the 2 link of the solutions that i've tried, but with no success http://stackoverflow.com/a/1472332/1326556
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1710252/1326556            Thanks for respond to me, i'm not happy to don't solve this problem, that take me 1mn in Php....

Comment: I've tried the very same ov your task without the macro (so using <TSTAMP/> directly after the <sleep>. It's not a matter of format, simply the timestamp seems always the same. It seems that once called via TSTAMP, you can only modify it through the use of the offset, but that makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to TSTAMP sources it should work (sources [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.6.3/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Tstamp.java.html#line.65)) The Date object is always instantiated. Maybe there's some weird task recycle going on behind the surface ?

I'm trying with this ant build file

```
<project name="testTStamp" default="xxx" basedir=".">
    <target name="testMe"> 
        <MyTimestamp> </MyTimestamp> 
        <sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
        <MyTimestamp> </MyTimestamp> 
    </target> 

    <macrodef name="MyTimestamp"> 
        <sequential > 
            <tstamp> 
                <format property="current.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"/> 
            </tstamp> 
            <echo message="RUN_TIME: ${current.time}"/> 
        </sequential> 
    </macrodef>

    <target name="default"> 
        <tstamp> 
            <format property="current.time_one" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa"/> 
        </tstamp> 
        <echo message="RUN_TIME: ${current.time_one}"/> 
        <sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
        <tstamp> 
            <format property="current.time_two" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa"/> 
        </tstamp> 
        <echo message="RUN_TIME: ${current.time_two}"/> 
    </target> 

    <target name='xxx' depends='default, testMe' />
</project>
```

Okay, if in the default target, I do change the name of the format property, it works. So there's some caching magik behind.

Comment: It's make me crazy !!! This sample of code seems to be good at look, so why it's doesn't work ? it's not logic !

Comment: @Jeffberthon: check the default task in my sample, it actually works. I guess there's some caching involved. Hacking the sources of TSTAMP I've checked that the java.util.Date object is  allocated upon the execution of the task, so it should work. If you use different property names is working. However is pretty strange.

Comment: Hi BigMike, it's effectively the only solution i've found, but it's not logic...If i want to display 5 date/time in the same Ant script, i  have to declare five proerty/name different...I continue like this....Thanks for looking my question ;-)                              Bye.

Comment: @Jeffberthon agree, it's pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

[Properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) are immutable in Ant; they are *not* variables.

However, you can probably achieve what you want by using the [`<local>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) task. This task causes a property set afterwards in the `target` (or `sequential`, or any other block) to be only specified locally.

So if all of your timestamp echos are in separate targets, then it will work.  Within a single target, you will still need to use multiple properties like "time_start", "time_end", etc.

Answer (score 0):

In follow up to this thread, I've read that a macrodef is a more appropriate method, as it keeps instantiating every time it is called, so no caching problems.  I've simplified their example.  I included my entire file, so you can just save out the code below as clock.xml and run it directly from ant.

```
<project name="marktime" basedir=".">
<description>
    logstamp is a simple macrodef for ANT to echo a time stamp out to an open log.
    It is not written to pass back the current time, just simple echo to stdout.
            You are welcome to add which file to output the results to, add blurbs to messages.

</description>

<macrodef name="logstamp">
  <sequential>
  <local name="logtime"/>
  <tstamp>
    <format property="logtime" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd : HH:mm:ss z"/>
  </tstamp>
  <echo  message=" ### Current time now: ${logtime}"/>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target
name="init"
description="boilerplate for all targets">
    <!-- Just run the Macrodef -->
<logstamp/>
<sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
<logstamp/>
<sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
<logstamp/>
<sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
<logstamp/>
<sleep seconds="5"> </sleep> 
<logstamp/>
</target>
</project>
```

The results are as follows:

```
C:\desktop\>ant -f clock.xml init
Buildfile: C:\desktop\clock.xml

init:
     [echo]  ### Current time now: 2014.02.14 : 16:41:06 PST
     [echo]  ### Current time now: 2014.02.14 : 16:41:11 PST
     [echo]  ### Current time now: 2014.02.14 : 16:41:16 PST
     [echo]  ### Current time now: 2014.02.14 : 16:41:21 PST
     [echo]  ### Current time now: 2014.02.14 : 16:41:26 PST

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 20 seconds
```

Comment: This solution makes use of <local> which requires Ant v1.8 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Bee Kay, this macro works with ANT version 1.7 by avoiding the use of 'local', using 'attribute' on the 'macrodef' instead:

```
<project name="echotime" basedir="." default="echotime">
<description>
echotime is a simple macrodef for ANT to echo a time stamp to an open log.
It is not written to pass back the current time, just simple echo to stdout.
</description>

<macrodef name="echotime">
    <attribute name="logtime" default="" />
    <sequential>
        <tstamp>
            <format property="logtime" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z" />
        </tstamp>
        <echo message="Build finished at ${logtime}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="echotime">
    <echo message="${ant.version}" />
    <echotime />
</target>
```

The results are as follows:

```
>ant -buildfile echotime.xml
Buildfile: echotime.xml

echotime:
     [echo] Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
     [echo] Build finished at 2019.12.19 11:43:29 EST

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```