# Printing time-stamp after each child module build in Maven

Tags: maven

I am building a number of maven projects from the level of their parent.Some of the projects have child modules of their own. Is there a way to print the time-stamp after each module is built?

Comment: What would you like to have? Can you show what you have and the target you would like to see?

Comment: In the console when build of ,say, sample-module1 is complete I see the following:
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Join notifier requires a CauseAction
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sample-module2 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Before the line "[INFO] Building sample-module2 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

I want to see the time-stamp

Comment: Simply use a continious integration solution like Jenkins which has a timestamper plugin which provides such things. Or check the [maven-profiler](https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler) which gives you much more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [maven ant-run plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).
You can add an execution bound the last step (install or deploy) which will print out the time stamp of your choice.
See [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472301/output-timestamp-in-ant) here.

Also you can try the [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and just run the system command `date` (linux) or `date /T` (windows).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Going this way you need to change your build which is not a good idea...Better use EventSpy to do such things. Or CI solutions like Jenkins which provide such things already.

Comment: I agree, although this assumes you use a 3rd party. IMHO, it's better to update the main pom (or a super pom) once and have it work the same all over.